# SQLite delete rows prior to date

Tags: sqlite

I have a column `timestamp` of data type `TEXT` in an SQLite table.

I want to delete everything prior to `2015-03-01 00:00:00` (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from tablename where timestamp < '2015-03-01 00:00:00';
```

The natural order of Strings (Text) is the same as of timestamps if your are using the date-format like above starting with the most significant value (year) on the left.